# Can't Login to Gnome 3 (No Login Screen) 13.04

Tags: gnome, login

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 the one from their website, then I installed Gnome 3 to try it but I don't have a login screen it just goes to unity. I did this before and I had the option on the login screen to choose unity or gnome or gnome classic but I don't anymore. If anyone could help that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the users section of your system settings and edit your account. Uncheck "automatic login" (may be labeled different, I'm using the german version). At next boot, the lightdm-greeter should appear and let you choose your favourite desktop environment.